# Force keyboard to show

Tags: keyboard

I have a situation where the input on a form consists of several dropdown fields but there is no submit button: it expects you to hit enter. But with no text field, the keyboard does not show. Is there any way to force the keyboard to show regardless of what's on the screen?

Note: a previous question asked about a possible bug where the keyboard does not show when it should because the cursor is in an input field. In my case, the keyboard is not prompted by an input field but I need it to pop up anyway. The previous question/answer/comments does not contain any answer to this issue.

Comment: Is this in a browser or an app? Are you the developer?

Comment: It was in a browser and no, I'm not the developer.

Comment: Report the problem to the website as well (in some jurisdictions, it may be infringing disability discrimination legislation)

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

As far as I know there is no possible way to do that.
But if your phone supports USB OTG, maybe try connecting a physical keyboard. That should work.

Comment: does seem the only solution. Bit overkill for that one website though ;)

Comment: Actually, I could have used Continuum, I guess.

Comment: Yeah that's also a viable option